# Unit testing function that calls other function

Tags: unit-testing, functional-programming, elixir

Say I have the following two functions:

```
add_five (number) -> number + 2

add_six (number) -> add_five(number) + 1
```

As you can see, `add_five` has a bug.

If I now test `add_six` it would fail because the result is incorrect, **but the code is correct**.

Imagine you have a large tree of functions calling each other, it would be hard to find out which function contains the bug, because all the functions will fail (and not only the one with the bug).

So my question is: should unit tests fail because of incorrect behaviour (wrong results) or because of incorrect code (bugs).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test a class that has private methods, fields or inner classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-to-test-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or-inner-classes)

Comment: No test can perform the magic to detect incorrect code. All it can do is detect incorrect behaviour.

Comment: Is it right to say that in that case unit tests don't really help to find bugs? It tells you that there is invalid behaviour, but doesn't directly tell you where the bug is.

Comment: Incorrect behaviour indicates the presence of a bug, not the location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> should unit tests fail because of incorrect behaviour (wrong results) or because of incorrect code (bugs)?

Unit tests usually fail because of wrong results. That's what you write in assertions: you call a method and you define the expected result.

Unit tests cannot identify incorrect code. If the operation is `return number+5` and your CPU or your RAM has a hardware problem and return something different, then the test will fail as well, even if the code is correct.

Also consider:

```
public int add_five(int number)
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    return number+5;
}
```

How shall the unit test know whether the Sleep is intended or not?

So, if any unit test fails, it's your job to look at it, find out why it fails and if it fails in a different method, write a new unit test for that method so you can exclude that method next time.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have a test for `add_five/1` and a test for `add_six/1`. In this case, the test for `add_six/1` will fail alongside the test for `add_five/1`.

Let's assume you decide to check `add_six/1` first. You see that it depends on `add_five/1`, which is also failing. You can immediately assume that the bug in `add_five/1` is cascading up.

Your module dependencies form a directed (hopefully acyclic) graph. If a dependency of you function or module is broken, that should be what you target for debugging first.

Another option is to mock out the `add_five` function when testing your `add_six`function, but this quickly creates a lot of extra typing and logic duplication. If you change the spec of `add_five`, you have to change every place you reimplemented it as a mock.

If you use a quickcheck-style testing library, you can test for certain logic errors based on the properties of what you're testing. These bugs are detected using randomly generated cases that produce incorrect results, but all you as a tester write are library-specific definitions of the properties you're testing for. However, this will also suffer from dependency breakages unless you've mocked out dependent modules/functions.